# convert microsoft.graph.customTimeZone into TimeZoneInfo

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

A Microsoft Graph API call is returning microsoft.graph.customTimeZone.
I need to convert it into TimezeoneInfo.

I searched for a while without finding how to do the conversion.
Can you share a function or API that would do this automatically?

"workingHours":
{"daysOfWeek":["monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday"],

"startTime":"08:00:00.0000000",

"endTime":"17:00:00.0000000",

"timeZone":{"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.customTimeZone",

"bias":360,

"name":"Customized Time Zone",

"standardOffset":{"time":"02:00:00.0000000",

"dayOccurrence":1,

"dayOfWeek":"sunday",

"month":11,

"year":0},

"daylightOffset":{"daylightBias":-60,

"time":"02:00:00.0000000",

"dayOccurrence":2,

"dayOfWeek":"sunday",

"month":3,

"year":0}}}}]}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your case the type is `microsoft.graph.customTimeZone`. So you have to convert the type by the following method.

When performing the conversion, the `ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset, TimeZoneInfo)` method applies any adjustment rules in effect in the `destinationTimeZone` time zone.

The below code sample will help you to convert the time zone.

```
public static DateTimeOffset ConvertTime (DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset, TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't contain any implementation

Comment: I don't want to convert the date, I want to read the microsoft.graph.customTimeZone and get a TimeZoneInfo from it.